# Is there a design pattern to aggregate asynchronous file processing

Tags: design-patterns

A file hits the system. The file contains multiple entities, each of which are processed individually and asynchronously by a multi-node Service Fabric stateless service.

The system needs to know when the final entity processes so the file can be marked as fully completed processing.

For example, a received file contains 150 entities. Each entity is queued in an Azure storage queue and picked up by a stateless service instance and processed. When the final entity processes the file should be marked as "processing complete."

Is there a concrete pattern or an abstract that defines this sort of process? Or perhaps a common design available?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the [Aggregator](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html) design pattern.

Create a correlation ID for the file and make sure to attach that ID to each of the entities that you enqueue.

Besides enqueueing all the entities, you also send a message with the same ID that only contains the total number of entities.

The entity handlers should publish an 'EntityCompleted' event with the correlation ID when they've handled an entity.

The Aggregator subscribes to these messages and counts how many entities have completed for each correlation ID. When the number of handled entities reach the total, the file can be marked as fully handled.

In general, if you're doing asynchronous messaging as you describe, you should buy and read [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/).